regex for capturing self parts (before and after), greedy match
I wish to get both matches USD 123 and 123 USD from a string USD 123 USD using a SINGLE REGEX.
Is this even possible?
The obvious regex ((USD)\s?(123)\s?)|(123\s?(USD)?) doesnt workout - this seems a bit lost to me.
Am I missing something obvious here?
EDIT 1 : The USD part is not constant and is ever changing as a variable from a configured list.
EDIT 2: Language preferred - python. Flexible to answers from other languages though.
Amazing to see the comments. Please add as an Answer so that I can accept the best one!

It is not possible. Any given character can only be captured at most once. Why do you need to capture something that is a constant -  you already know what it is. What is it that you;re tyring to acheive?

If you want to capture overlapping matches, you need to capture inside a lookahead. If you use Python there is PyPI regex which even provides an overlapped fag. In PCRE you could do something like this: (?|(123 USD)|(?=(USD 123))) so it's essential to know your environment.

What language are you using?

@bobblebubble Another solution in PCRE without capture: USD 123|(?<=\K123 )USD. Note that resetting the match start (\K) within the look-behind assertion is not allowed in regex101.com, but it is fine in PHP.

@Steve4585 Amazing idea, thank you for sharing! When I see your regex, I thought <this can't work>  but it looks like it does.

@Bohemian forgot to add this - the USD part is not a constant, trying to make a dynamic regex here from a configured list.

"USD" is not constant? Can it be any 3-letter currency code? Please provide a few examples in your question and what you want captured from it.

Consider it the list of all currencies in the world.
Amazing to see the comments. Please add as an Answer so that I can accept the best one! I believe I may have found the answer on @bobblebubble 's answer

The answer depends on the environment you're using. In most regex flavors that support capturing groups and lookarounds, overlapping matches can be captured inside a lookahead.

Using PHP (PCRE) and a branch reset to get matches in the same group:
(?|(123 USD)|(?=(USD 123)))

See this demo at regex101. It either normally matches and captures the left option of the alternation OR captures the right option inside a lookahead to the same first group.
In this variant the substring that gets overlapped needs to be put into the lookahead to prevent getting the part consumed and allow normal matching of the other option. In PHP you can get the matches of the first group using preg_match_all ⇒ PHP demo at tio.run.
I hope also @Steve4585 will convert his comment into an answer, new to me this method!

Using Python and alternative PyPI regex module:
There is an overlapped flag available, which allows a very basic pattern (Python demo).
m = regex.findall(r"USD 123|123 USD", s, overlapped=True)




++ learnt about overlapped=True of regex module
